Which EPSG does SUMO use?
I want to connect sumo with unreal engine use real world map.
According to this page (https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Distances.html), Sumo simulation network uses multiple coordination system:

x,y,z: coordinates in meters (Cartesian coordinates)
lon,lat,z: geo-coordinates + elevation in meters (typically WGS84) if the network is geo-referenced
edgeID, laneIndex, lanePosition: The lanePosition is the driving distance from the start of the edge (road) in meters

But it doesnt specify which EPSG is used by default for SUMO?
Anyone has clue?

The typical net conversion starting from OpenStreetMap data will convert to UTM. The UTM zone will be determined from the first coordinate pair which is being converted (so basically the first node in your OSM file).
